# Change the link to deleted recent answer in case the question has been deleted

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, visibility

Currently if a question is deleted, users with <10K will see a *broken* link in their list of deleted answers.

For example, on one of the sites [a link to one of my answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115859/awk-verify-array-values-with-awk-one-liner-command/115862#115862) results into a 404 page.  However, it turns out that I can see my answer still by looking at the [post revisions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/115862/revisions) instead.

Could we have a link to the post revisions instead in the list of deleted answers for users who don't have the required privilege, i.e. less than 10K?  As is, the link to deleted answer is rather useless in case the post has been deleted and it's not quite obvious that an alternate link *can* provide access.

Comment: It would still be confusing; I can already see the questions here on Meta: *Why do some of my deleted answer links go to the revisions page, while others go to the actual post*?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps less confusing than: _One can always see their own posts even if those are deleted_ and still end up in _404_.

Comment: Sure, just pointing out the one slight problem with the idea. Note: I did not downvote your suggestion either. :-P