# Can I see a question which now shows as "removed" on my reputation points page?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I understand that when a question is deleted, you lose any reputation points which was earned in editing or answering that question, but I can't see a way to actually view the question any more once it's been deleted (for example, if you wanted to see the exact close/delete reason(s), or review the content and challenge the decision to close or delete it).

Is it possible to see these posts? Am I unable to do so due to only having ~900 reputation points on the site in question?

Comment: No, without [Access To Moderator Tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (10k rep) you can't and shouldn't see deleted questions that you didn't write yourself, period.

Comment: Ok, thanks @ShadowWizard, feel free to post as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I unable to do so due to only having ~900 rep on the site in question?

You can only see deleted questions (that aren't your own) with the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) privilege (10k on graduated sites); otherwise you're out of luck.

You can see reputation changes from deleted posts under the reputation tab of your profile, just make sure "show removed posts" is checked and look for anything with the "removed" label. If you have the ability to see the relevant post then the title there will link to it—so look there first.

> [image]

The only other options...

You can see your own deleted recent questions (recent questions that were deleted; not recently deleted questions) under the questions tab of your profile, just click the "deleted recent questions" link below the list of answers. So if the question was your own it may be there.

Similarly, you can see your deleted recent answers under the answers tab of your profile. You can only see these if you have the ability to see the question that they were posted to though.

Interestingly, according to [Change the link to deleted recent answer in case the question has been deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223433/307988) you can see the revision history of your answer even if you can't see the question (that doesn't help you much in seeing the question though).

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to see these posts?

No, without the [Access To Moderator Tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)  (10k rep on graduated sites) you can see only your own deleted questions and you can't (and shouldn't) see deleted questions written by others.

If you have the direct link to the question that was deleted (e.g. from your browser's history) you can ask in chat for a high rep user to take a look and tell you why it was deleted.

Comment: Sorry, [Cai](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307988/cai) jumped in with a slightly more detailed answer just before you - still upvoted though, thanks for the help!

Comment: Cheers, leaving this one too as it contains bit more info.